# Retrieving term ids for taxonomy field

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I'm running into slow performance related to select N+1 issues when accessing the taxonomy terms associated with content items of a custom content type.

I've worked around issues like this in the past by getting all the related content ids up front and so I can use the ContentManager's GetMany method to get them all in one shot. For example, this has worked well for the MediaLibraryPickerField as I can easily get at the media content ids using the Ids property on the field. Here's an example similar to what I've done: [Eager loading a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23806766/eager-loading-a-field)

I'd like to use a similar approach for getting taxonomy terms but I can't figure out how to get the term ids for a Taxonomy field on my content item. It seems that I can only access the lazy loaded term part which results in a select N+1 as they are retrieved for each content item.

Is there a way to get just the term ids for a taxonomy field without retrieving the whole term? I've spent some time digging around in the Taxonomy module source but I'm not finding any way to do it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to inject `IRepository<TermContentItem>`?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy - Thanks for the suggestion! I had not thought about that.

Comment: Adding it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to inject `IRepository<TermContentItem>`. You should then be able to query over that, going beyond what the service offers natively.